# Resetting numberOfLogs and Updating date field if passed 10 minute mark

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to figure out what I need to do so that it can see if after the account gets locked if its at that 10 minute mark passed the lockDate if there is a lockDate other than the 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and then if is then turn the lockDate back to 0000-00-00 and resets the numberOfLogins.

My Code: http://pastebin.com/vFZwmJuc

Answer (score 0):

That gives you the users which have a lock time >= 10 Minutes

```
SELECT userID  lockDate from manager_users where lockDate > '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and lockDate <=  NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

All you need to do then, is updating the lockDate to '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

```
$query = 'UPDATE manager_users set lockDate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' where userID = '. intval($userID) .' LIMIT 1';
```

(presuming userID is your primary key)